# An error when approving a post at Stack Overflow Documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, review-suspension

Why does the following error happen when I try to approve a post?

[image: Error when approving a post]

Comment: It's possible this is related to review bans. We rolled out audits for Proposed Changes review this week. That error message isn't very informative, however.

Comment: the error was not clear, this is not my fault, we are here to ask not to punish each other with downvote

Comment: Downvotes are different on Meta.

Answer (score 10):

You're currently banned from review due to failing audits on Stack Overflow proper, which makes you unable to review Documentation edits.

I should note that you should review each of the audit failures before performing a single additional review. There is a disturbing pattern to these. This is getting to be enough of a problem for us that any additional review bans may also be accompanied by an account suspension.

Comment: It should definitely display a better error though. "An error has occurred" is not at all helpful (it looks like a server error).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Normally they can't even get into the review queues while under a suspension so I assume they found a way in (or docs was forgotten about) and so the only thing left for the system to do was issue a vague error.  They probably just need to make sure they can't get ito the queue in the first place.