# How can I delete my question if it has an answer?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, meta

How can I delete my Meta question that already has an answer? When I try to delete it, it says:

[image: Close question]

So I flagged it for moderator attention, but no one responds. What should I do now?

Comment: Link to the question?

Comment: for example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338169/can-i-ask-a-question-that-not-related-to-any-problem-just-to-create-a-tag

Comment: and this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336258/error-when-approving-a-post-at-stack-overflow-documentation

Comment: And *why* do you feel that the question merits deletion.

Comment: for me, because there are many down votes, like this case, i try to delete it  but i can't and this not fair!

Comment: When did you flag the question? The moderators are very busy volunteers  with actual jobs and, in some cases, maybe even actual lives so you may not always get responses as quickly as you'd like.

Comment: Just as an FYI, [this is considered abusive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270538/should-i-delete-my-own-questions-with-answers/270539#270539). It could incur penalties

Comment: @Machavity It's abusive *if you're deleting quality content* that would be helpful to others.  It's *appropriate* and *helpful* if you're deleting low quality content that doesn't belong on the site in the first place.  Of course, the OP has not yet made a case that the post he wants to delete in fact merits deletion (of course, nor has the case been made that the post is helpful either).

Comment: @Machavity Oh, and there is no post ban on per site metas, so no, there are no [automatic] penalties (or course, if moderators notice you consistently posting low quality content, or taking other inappropriate actions such as deleting quality content out of spite, they may choose to intervene manually).

Comment: Note that diamond moderators provided explanation why [the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338169/can-i-ask-a-question-that-not-related-to-any-problem-just-to-create-a-tag) should not be deleted - " Ed Cottrell♦, 2016-11-25: We prefer not to delete questions that folks have taken the time to contribute answers to"... so please clarify what kind of additional responses you need.

Comment: @MrLY - You *did* receive a response from a moderator. We declined your flag on November 28. Check your flag responses here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5558072

Comment: @Brad Larson why you declined my flags? what are the reasons about that? can you explain more?

Comment: @MrLY - I didn't decline the flag, but we typically don't delete questions with upvoted answers unless those answers would be of no use to anyone outside of the asker. Almost all flags requesting deletion of questions that have upvoted answers are declined.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot delete questions with (upvoted) answers, neither on the main Stack Overflow site or on Meta. This is because *you* might be satisfied with the answer and not need it anymore, but it can still be of value to *future visitors* to the site with the same/related problems.

You can request for the question to be [*disassociated*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request) from your account by using the [Contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form.

Comment: so, in this case i can't delete this question, because there are an answer, and this is not good, because for me it contain many down votes, so i think you need to find a way to delete it, because the user is free to let it or to delete it, i'm wrong?

Comment: Downvotes on Meta don't cost you any reputation, and it's very hard to get a question ban here (because it's very easy to score downvotes). So I'd consider it a (hard) lesson.

Comment: yes i know it not cost me any reputation, but in the other StackOverflow sites, it do!

Comment: @MrLY: but aren't you happy that apparently you don't have to worry for the votes here, then?

Comment: i should to worry, because the question is asked by my name, so for me it is shame to get a reputation like this

Comment: @Glorfindel When you post content on SE it is *absolutely* your own.  You still own it, you're just giving other people permission to also publish it (and use it themselves), so long as they cite you.  It doesn't make it not yours.

Comment: @Servy then why is [vandalism of your own content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288748/4751173) prohibited? IANAL, and the way I worded it is the easiest for me to explain it.

Comment: @Glorfindel Because you gave SE (and everyone in the world) the right to host your original content when you posted it.  You still own the content, but you no longer have the right to prohibit SE (or anyone else) from publishing it.  You can, however, still apply other licences to it, give people permission to use it *without* the CC-Wiki restrictions (for attribution and applying the licence to derived works), use it yourself without citation or applying that licence's restrictions to it, etc., things that anyone else *wouldn't* be able to do.

Comment: @MrLY: "*i should to worry, because the question is asked by my name, so for me it is shame to get a reputation like this*" Your question is still a valid question which contains useful information. There's no reason to get it deleted, just because you personally don't want to be associated with a question that is negatively voted. This site exists to serve the needs of more people than just you.

Comment: @MrLY also, if you were concerned about a question associated with your account having downvotes, you could have done more research, read the guidance and written a better one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message in your picture already gives you all the information you need in order to attempt to get it deleted.

You will need to flag the question for moderator attention and explain why you want it deleted. They will have to make a decision if the question is worth keeping around or can be deleted.

You can also ask for the question to be disassociated from your account which means it will no longer be able to be identified as a post you made.

Information on disassociating a post: [What is the proper route for a dissociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request)